# jQuery src replace crossfade on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade, src

I have a couple of images on my Joomla site, each one with a black&white version and a color version. I'd like to change a part of the src ('bw' to 'color') when hovered over with a nice crossfade. I'm very new to jQuery, so the only code I have is this, which is probably completely wrong.

```
$(".grey img").mouseover(function() {
$(this).attr('src', function(i, src) {
    return src.replace( 'bw', 'color' ).fadeIn(800);
});
$(".grey img").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', function(i, src) {
        return src.replace( 'color', 'bw' ).fadeOut();
});
```

I've searched for a solution for hours and at this point I'm not sure if it's really obvious and I'm completely missing it. So, sorry if it is, or if there is a solution somewhere and I didn't look enough.

I would like to solve this without having to link two images in the html, but if there's no other solution, I would be thankful for any tips on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the source initially before you can change it. I'll also clean it up a bit:

```
$('.grey').on({
    mouseenter:function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            src = $this.attr('src').replace('bw','color');

        $this.fadeOut(function(){
            $this
                .attr('src',src)
                .on('load',function(){
                    $this.fadeIn();
                });
        });
    },
    mouseleave:function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            src = $this.attr('src').replace('color','bw');

        $this.fadeOut(function(){
            $this
                .attr('src',src)
                .on('load',function(){
                    $this.fadeIn();
                });
        });
    }
},'img');
```

As you can see, you were on the right track, but you just need to capture the source before you can manipulate it. The other changes I made were:

- Using `.on()` which allows for single binding event
- Using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`
- Delegating `.on()` assignments to all `img` contained in `.grey`

Also I used a variable for cleanliness of reading, but you could have just as easily placed the `$(this).attr('src').replace('bw','color')` in the assignment and foregone the variable entirely.

**EDIT** - updated to show fadeIn/fadeOut on image change.

Comment: Oh, great, thank you so much!!! :D Do you think there's a way to get it to fade in and out, instead of just jumping to the other picturne?

Comment: Thank you again, you're really fast! =) It works perfectly! ... Except, there's absolutely no way to make it crossfade, right? I read that a lot, that you can't make that flash of nothingness disappear. Sorry for the many questions!

Comment: yeah unfortunately no, not unless you preload all of the images side-by-side and kind of fade one in while the other fades out. your page would take twice as long to load though, and both your CSS and JS would be radically different with that setup.